# Is there a more painless way to call Win32 from C#?

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport

Every few months I find myself needing to call Win32 from C#. Though I've done it a dozen times, I've usually forgotten the exact machinations, so I poke around the web or old code and figure out what DllImport statements I need, etc.

Am I alone?

Is there a sanctioned "Win32" class that has the requisite declarations for the entire Win32 API? Seems like there ought to be. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Definitely not alone. +1

Comment: pinvoke.net is great but a single assembly to reference would be so nice...

Comment: I definitely *don't* want a single compiled assembly.  The Win32 API is huge.  I mean *really* huge.  Dragging around thousands of API declarations just to get the one you want would be a real chore.  Better to have the declarations as source code and copy the ones you want.

Comment: Dragging around? A single referenced assembly that organized the calls into enums, structs and classes would be extraordinarily useful. Especially if it was documented. But, to each his own, I guess. For me, I'll take the assembly.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to have. I can only assume that Microsoft wanted to discourage people--especially those who might not understand all the ramifications--from crossing the inter-op boundary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find http://www.pinvoke.net helpful.

Also, for common Win32 functions, you could try the [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/06/23/p-invoke-interop-assistant-justin-van-patten.aspx).

Comment: PInvoke Interop Assistant can also be used to translate C code straight to the appropriate signatures and functions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no sanctioned Win32 class, but http://www.pinvoke.net is a great central resource for these things.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a great idea for an open source project.

/em puts on thinking cap, and runs of to pinvoke.net

Answer (score 1):

Getting to the correct DllImport statements are easy like everyone is saying, but for ease if use I usually wrap the Win32 functions I need in C# classes and compile into my core helper assembly. So next time I just reference the assembly. So if I need some Win32 function, chances are it is already in my helper lib if not I just add it.

Also I map the return codes to Exceptions rather, i.e. if the HResult is non zero I throw an Exception so my C# apps do not need to know about HResult or return codes ever.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and search for Win32Native.  It has a bunch of definitions that you could use for PInvoking.